# Is there a way to disable cache only for a single template file?

Tags: 8, caching

For my view I need to update my fields dynamically, for this reason I need to disable cache for views-view-field.html.twig, as it takes the parameter from a contextual filter.
I send an argument from `template_preprocess_views_view_field()` to the template file.

I know how to disable the caching of template files for developers, but I cannot use it on the production system, as it may affect the performance. So the issue for me is disabling the cache only for a single template.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use the value of your field to set a custom cache tag in your view, that should invalidate the cache whenever your field value changes.

```
template_preprocess_views_view_field(&$variables) {
  $view = $variables['view'];
  $parameter = 'my_custom_field_that_is_sent_as_argument_to_twig';
  $view->element['#cache']['tags']['custom_parameter:' . $parameter];
}
```